# c# linq retrieve dictionary value subset

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two sets

```
Dictionary<int, Person[]> peopleSet = new() 
{
   { 1, new [] { new Person(11), new Person(22) } },
   { 2, new [] { new Person(33), new Person(44), new Person(55) } },
   { 3, new [] { new Person(66), new Person(77), new Person(88) } },
}

IEnumerable<int> ages = new [] { 11, 33, 44 };
```

I want to use linq to get all peopleSet records with the final result

```
// How to use linq to retrieve the set below

Dictionary<int, Person[]> peopleSetLinq = new() 
{
   { 1, new [] { new Person(11) } },
   { 2, new [] { new Person(33), new Person(44) } }
}
```

I want the keys and only the values that match based on the Person param passed in the constructor

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; init; }

   public Person(int id)
   {
      Id = id;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ?

Comment: I can use a loop but if there's a way using linq, just a preference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can convert `ages` to a `HashSet` so testing is efficient. (For very small data, this may be a waste of time, but it will scale better than not doing it.)

Then, you can filter the `Dictionary` `KeyValuePair`s by having `Person`s matching `ages` and convert to a new `Dictionary`:

```
var filterPeople = ages.ToHashSet();
var ans = peopleSet.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<int, Person[]>(
                                    kvp.Key,
                                    kvp.Value.Where(p => filterPeople.Contains(p.Id)).ToArray())) // filter Person[] to match ages
                   .Where(kv => kv.Value.Any()) // throw away empty peopleSet entries
                   .ToDictionary();
```

NOTE: Answer modified to use standard `KeyValuePair<,>` and to properly type `Value` to be `Person[]`.

Comment: There may be probably 100s of keys and each key could have maybe upwards to 100 people. My goal isn't efficiency but good to know this.

Comment: Efficiency should be a habit @HelloWorld :-)

Comment: HashSet is the way... Agreed totally

Comment: Checkout [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-8.0) tho

Comment: @teamol `Lookup` is for indexing collections to a key, and can't easily be modified. It is not a replacement for `HashSet` or `Dictionary`.